# How to pass data from child component to parent component without the child component rerendering in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My child component is an accordion with controls in it. The problem is, everytime you input data on the controls and it triggers an onChange event which passes its data to its parent component, the accordion closes/collapses and I don't need that behavior.

The accordion is just imported from a library and I can't change its behavior.

Is there anyway to prevent this or pass props/data from child component to parent component without rerendering/restarting DOM of child component?

Parent component:

```
  const ParentComponent = () => {

  const handleChangeChildAccordion = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
  }

  return (
    <ChildComponentAccordion currentData={currentData} onChangeTPAccordion={handleChangeChildAccordion}/> }
  );
}
```

Child Component:

```
const ChildComponent = (props) => {

  const onDataChangeHandler = (e) => {
       props.onChangeTPAccordion(e);
    };

    return (
      <Accordion onChange={onDataChangeHandler}/>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The child component doesn't *remount*, it *rerenders*. Normally, a component rerenders any time any its parent rerenders. To avoid that you:

- Avoid changing the child component's props, and
- *Memoize* the child component so it doesn't rerender when its props don't change in a way it cares about.

You do the first by ensuring that, for instance, callbacks you pass the component are *stable* (they don't change on every render). In a function component, you do it by using [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo), [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback), and/or [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref). In a class component, you typically do that by making the callbacks properties on the component instance that aren't recreated.

You do the second by using [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) (if it's a function component) or for a `class` component by extending [`PureComponent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) (for simple memoization) or implementing [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate).

You haven't given us much code to work with, so here's a simple example:

```js
const { useState, useCallback, useRef } = React;

const log = (...msgs) => console.log(...msgs);

const Child1 = React.memo(({value, doUpdate}) => {
    log(`Child1 rendering`);
    return <div>
        Child1 - Value: {value} <input type="button" value="+" onClick={doUpdate} />
    </div>;
});

const Child2 = React.memo(({value, doUpdate}) => {
    log(`Child2 rendering`);
    return <div>
        Child2 - Value: {value} <input type="button" value="+" onClick={doUpdate} />
    </div>;
});

const Parent = () => {
    log(`Parent rendering`);
    const [counter1, setCounter1] = useState(0);
    const [counter2, setCounter2] = useState(0);

    // `useCallback` remembers the first function you pass it and returns
    // it to you, only returning the new one you pass it if the
    // dependencies array changes. This is one way to create a stable
    // callback.
    const update1 = useCallback(() => setCounter1(c => c + 1), []);

    // `useRef` gives you an object you can put arbitrary properties on,
    // which is another way to have a stable callback.
    const update2Ref = useRef(null);
    if (!update2Ref.current) {
        update2Ref.current = () => setCounter2(c => c + 1);
    }
    const update2 = update2Ref.current;

    return <div>
        <Child1 value={counter1} doUpdate={update1} />
        <Child2 value={counter2} doUpdate={update2} />
    </div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

[TypeScript playground with types added](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxLZFIDCKANgwEboDW1xyAZnAL5xuUCCDgAiKKgxiA3ACg5aCADtC8BhADmcALxwAFADpjIQpsIAuOCmUBPANoBdAJS6AfHCWqIDJIY2aRiZmhM7ycsDKlFDc6EhwtAAWwAwAJgAKwmCEuHJw+XAAboz4SFbK+CDMSFDyBXCpEACqYKkUZQauOh6FEMCp8nyKKmoJyWkAjLqIUjCGIEggEPr6OMUMpdiNLW2UfFZJKRlZoe659QH6AAaHk3CSyqk1kZpXYXkFkjD4UMpwADypYCFNwfer5W6pKYAWjgADUSh01oiBP9ImB8PAYLYwEgdGJmJiYCoxEVEfiANSklS0BjANBsHQ4batdoCAD0oPq-3ZQJBg3ew1U8EhACZpsh0HMFksVsiNlQGs1WXsDuNjhBsl0PDgwXBLjd1eKHk8oC83nVPkhvr8AXyueCIUa4LCEQqrPLSqj0Zi4NjcfjCTBicpSetSpTqcpafTGczlbskByHfkefaBeEvKN0igHvA9PptecCgac3n7khHs9lK93vUs-B7Ep8FEahNsMQYLQIC3ohNHNMaGR2voAAx1goNuBNnutqCijvW7u9mqigd6IfkShjwX1dnsuBXGj0JisBlXCsy6pQHIwRLxbjAG-wbgtjDAFRwWw9uBgFCEHJgHgGxUgrG1VD1fc4CAv0IC-HtsBUBhbDAn5lBeP17zgZQkAAdzgFR4m-fBf3-QD4GAXg7yQSCDyeXEq2UNBgCQHJcygFAULQRIbE0VjDDgAAVZJAJyQi4FwzjYM8SR2msOA1BQZhfFozxGBYdhDD1Kd8BVJApg3YgTw0hkViLTtlznCZ9DQM5bIpOAJmcbAnF3AooKPLgkG4C9NGBVj4JImwCOYAArJAMECtS-gxYCoGYICOKgFCwCyGoYBYsTlEwVTcOSbjoLY5QIGoqAJKk4k4B4wp4hQBTyGU+I0HUs82C0+sRngXTE1FHhBy87h-jMs5en6VwAB9sPwJg3H0ComAnfJKIMABCbr2l67zDDQH481cXVHXydbKE27htt2yt806M4LNnaJRRsuy4AcpzLXyIYOuFAg9PFDcfp4c6oDzcJ6i+NC7WBFNwX+SEpnDPEcGbKyBBZRMmWO-Tkz1bkxTJBUmSR+6UYTdp0Z+rHuV5SHBnkIA)

That shows two different ways of making acallback stable (`useCallback` and `useRef`). (`useMemo` is what `useCallback` uses under the hood, so I didn't do an example of it.)

In that example, notice how the child telling the parent to update its counter doesn't cause the *other* child to re-render. That's because:

- We don't change the other child's props (because our callbacks are stable and the other child's counter didn't change), and
- We've memoized the child components

You can customize whether the component re-renders by passing a second argument to `React.memo` which is a function that says whether the new props coming in are "the same" (for rendering purposes) as the previous ones. By default, `React.memo` does a simple `===` comparison on each prop. And again, for `class` components, `PureComponent` does the simple `===` comparison, or you can implement `shouldComponentUpdate` yourself for more finely-tuned checks.

Comment: Hi, i am having an error on this part "const Child2 = React.memo(({value, doUpdate})". It says "Property 'value' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'"

Comment: @user10860402 - The demo above is just in JavaScript, you'll need to add types to it for TypeScript. I was answering the *conceptual* question of how you do this, not providing copy-and-paste code. You should be able to add the necessary types.

Comment: @user10860402 - ...but I've added a TypeScript playground link with types added. (I didn't use `React.FC`. I don't recall the details, but I understand it's not really recommended [anymore?].)

Comment: Thank you so much. I am currently still applying to my codes but not having so much luck, the child component still re-render when its data is passed to the parent component. also can i ask how to access the passed data using useRef and useCallBack?

Comment: @user10860402 - I'm afraid I don't understand the question. You don't access props with hooks.

Comment: in my question, what I am passing from the child component is an object that contains 2 dates. I can successfully passed that to parent but the child component re-renders every time and I need it to not re-render because the accordions closes every time it re-renders. Sorry if I confused you and I learned new things in your answer but I still cannot do what I need to do.

Comment: @user10860402 - When the child updates the parent, do either of the dates change? (Separately: It's odd for an Accordion component to change state when rerendering. Rerendering is completely normal and shouldn't affect the state of a component.) But basically, the above is all the help I can give you based on what you have in the question. I could help you more if you did a [mre] in the question, preferably using Stack Snippets (as I did in the answer). Details [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Basically I have 2 date pickers inside an accordion in the child component, and when the "onchange" event of either date pickers are triggered, It create an object and put the value of 2 dates there and pass that object back to its parent component. hence every time I pick a date the event triggers and the accordion closes. Thank you i will try my best to do a stack snippet.